# How should I be using the TPL if I want to do implement this threading concept?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I have a method like `SaveAsync(Item item)` and I need to call it on 10 `Item`s and the calls are independent of one another. I imagine the ideal way in terms of threading is *like*

```
Thread A | Run `SaveAsync(item1)` until we hit the `await` | ---- ... ---- | Run `SaveAsync(item10)` until we hit the `await` | ---------------------------------------|
Thread B | --------------------------------------------------- | Run the stuff after the `await` in `SaveAsync(item1)` | ------------------ ... -----------------------|  
Thread C | ------------------------------------------------------ | Run the stuff after the `await` in `SaveAsync(item2)` | ------------------ ... --------------------|  
.
.
.
```

(with it being possible that some of the stuff after the `await` for multiple items is run in the same thread, perhaps even Thread A)

I'm wondering how to write that in C#? Is it a parallel foreach or a loop with with await `SaveAsync(item)` or what?

Comment: Just a FYI, Parallel.ForEach and async code do not mix at all. They are systems from two different generations of TPL. You should look in to [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) instead.

Comment: What does it mean " Run `SaveAsync(item1)` until we hit the `await`? DO you mean "in" as an await that is inside SaveAsync method or "in" as in case of await SaveAsync(); If first, then simply calling var task1 = SaveAsync(item1) will execute SaveAsync up to first incomplete await inside SaveAsync method and will return synchronously allowing you to do something in mean time and await on completion with await task1; or execute another SaveAsync. You should specify what SaveAsync does because if it is something like save file then it does not have to be scheduled to own thread with Task.Run

Comment: @user7127000 If one of the answers solved your problem, please mark it as resolved to close this thread. If not please clarify what is still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where people do most of the mistakes with async/await:

1) Either people think, that everything after calling async method, with/without awaiting, does translate to ThreadPool thread.

2) Or people think that async does run synchronously.

The truth is somewhere between and @Iqon's statement about next block of code is actually incorrect: *"The only main difference here, is all tasks are executed in the same thread."*

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    tasks.Add(SaveAsync(item)); // No await here
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // will only continue when all tasks are finished (or cancelled or failed)
```

To make statement like this would suggest that the async method SaveAsync(item) is actually capable to execute fully and completely synchronously.

Here are examples:

```
async Task SaveAsync1(Item item)
{
    //no awaiting at all
}   

async Task SaveAsync2(Item item)
{
    //awaiting already completed task
    int i = await Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Methods like these would really run synchronously on thread it the async task was executed on. But these kind async methods are special snowflakes. There is no operation awaited here, everything is commplete even when await is inside the method, because it does not await on first case and does await on completed task in second case, so it synchronously continues after await and these two calls would be same:

```
var taskA = SaveAsync2(item);//it would return task runned to completion

//same here, await wont happen as returned task was runned to completion
await SaveAsync2(item);
```

So, making statements, that executing async method here synchronously is correct only in this special case:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    tasks.Add(SaveAsync2(item));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // will only continue when all tasks are finished (or cancelled or failed)
```

And there is no need to store tasks and await Task.WhenAll(tasks), it is all already done and this would be enough:

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    SaveAsync2(item);
    //it will execute synchronously because there is
    //nothing to await for in the method
}
```

Now lets explore real case, an async method that actualy awaits something inside or spark awaitable operation:

```
async Task SaveAsync3(Item item)
{
    //awaiting already completed task
    int i = await Task.FromResult(0);

    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Now what would this do?

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    tasks.Add(SaveAsync3(item));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // will only continue when all tasks are finished (or cancelled or failed)
```

Would it run synchronously? No!

Would it run concurrently in parallel? NO!

As I said at begining, the truth is somewhere between with async methods unless they are special snow flakes like SaveAsync1 and SaveAsync2.

So what the code did? It executed each SaveAsync3 synchronously up to await Task.Delay where it found the returned task is incomplete and returned back to caller and provided incomplete task which was stored to tasks and next SaveAsync was executed in same way.

Now await Task.WhenAll(tasks); has really meaning, because it is awaiting some incomplete operation which will run outside this thread context and in parallel.
All those parts of SaveAsync3 method after *await Task.Delay* will be scheduled to ThreadPool and will run in parallel, unless special case like UI thread context and in that case ConfigureAwait(false) after TaskDelay would be needed.

Hope you guys understand, what I want to say. You can not really say how async method will run unless you have more information about it or code.

This exercise also opens question, when to Task.Run on async method.
It is often missused and I think, that there are really just 2 main cases:

1) When you want break from current threads context, like UI, ASP.NET etc

2) When async method has synchronous part(up to first incomplete await) which is computationally intensive and you want to offload it as well, not just the incomplete await part. The case would be if SaveAsync3 would be computing the variable *i* for long time, let's say Fibonacci :).

For example you do not have to use Task.Run on something like SaveAsync which would open file and save into it something asynchronously, unless the synchronous part before first await inside SaveAsync is an issue, taks time. Then Task.Run is in order as is part of case 2).

Answer (score 2):

Per default `async` tasks will always return to the thread context they were started on. You can change this by adding

```
await task.ConfigureAwait(false)
```

This allows tells the runtime that you do not care on which thread context the task will resume and the runtime can omit the capture of the current thread context (which is quite costly).

However per default you will always be scheduled on the thread context that started the task.

There are a fewer default contexts, such as the ui thread context or the thread pool context. A task started on the ui thread context will be scheduled back to the ui thread context. 
A tasks started on the thread pool context will be scheduled to the next free thread from the pool. Not necessarily the same thread the task was started on.

However you can provide your own context if you need more control over the task scheduling.

How to start multiple task in a fashion as you described above. A loop will not help here. Lets take this example.

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    await SaveAsync(item);
}
```

The `await` here will wait until the `SaveAsync` finishes. So all saves are processed in sequence.

**How to save truly asynchronous?**

The trick is to start all tasks, but not await them, until all tasks are started. You then `wait` all tasks with `WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task>)`.

Here an example.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    tasks.Add(SaveAsync(item)); // No await here
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // will only continue when all tasks are finished (or cancelled or failed)
```

Because of the missing await, all "Save-Actions" are placed in the Async/Await state machine. As soon as the first task yields back, the second will be executed. This will result in a behavior somewhat similar to the one described in your question.

The only main difference here, is all tasks are executed in the same thread. This is most of time complete ok, because all `Save` methods usually need to access the same resources. Parallelizing them gives no real advantage, because the bottleneck is this resource.

**How to use mutliple threads**

You can execute a task on a new thread by using

```
Task.Run(SaveAsync(item));
```

This will execute the thread on a new thread taken from the thread pool, but there is no wait to start a new thread and finish the method on the ui thread.

To execute all items on different thread, you can use nearly the same code as before:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(SaveAsync(item));); // No await here
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // will only continue when all tasks are finished (or cancelled or failed)
```

The only difference is here, that we take the taks returned form `StartNew`.

**One remark:** Using `Task.Run` does not guarantee you a new thread. It will execute the task on the next free thread from the thread pool. This depends on your local settings as well as the local configuration (e.g. a heavy barebone server will have a lot more threads than any consumer laptop).

Whether you get a new thread or you have to wait for any occupied thread to finish is completely up to the thread pool. (The tread pool usually does a really great job. For more info, here a really great article on the thread pool performance: [CLR-Thread-Pool](http://mattwarren.org/2017/04/13/The-CLR-Thread-Pool-Thread-Injection-Algorithm/))

Comment: Instead of Task.Factory.StartNew it's preferred to use Task.Run, except in more advanced use-cases where you need to specify the TaskScheduler to use or define the TaskCreationOptions. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2, especially the linked blog entry in the remarks section.

Comment: "The only main difference here, is all tasks are executed in the same thread." Actually no, they are not executed in the same thread, only complete part of the async method is executed synchronously, look on my answer...

Comment: @ipavlu just because there are executed asynchronously does not mean there are executed on another thread. I do agree with your answer, but I do not think that it changes the content or meaning of mine.

Comment: Well, it very much depends on the current synchronization context. If the code is executed in the UI thread, you are correct, it will run synchronous part and incomplete awaited continuations will be scheduled to UI context. If in main (it would have to be wrapped into async method and called directly and wait on results), but then scheduling for incomplete parts would go to DefaultScheduler, ThreadPool.

Comment: We should not actually think about threads, but synchronization contexts. In the case of UI, there is UI thread and related synchronization context, that schedules work to the UI thread. In the main function of a console app, there is no synchronization context, the current is null, then it defaults to DefaultScheduler, ThreadPool. There is really no advantage to schedule back to the same thread. Thread can be reused in thread pool by something else and continuation can be easily executed by another thread with free hands.